# Append row to an empty data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone please explain me how I add a row to an empty data frame?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([], columns = ['abc', 'def'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 10]], columns = ['abc', 'def'] )

df1.append(df2)
df1
```

Just trying to understand the example in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html).

`df1` is still empty.

Comment: `df1 = df1.append(df2)` i.e. `append` is not in place.

Comment: the operation is **not** in place

Comment: @not_speshal yes, of course :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to updade df1 , like this

```
df1 = df1.append(df2)
```